# Relaunch application when the screen is unlocked

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When the application is on and when we leave it to idle, the screen gets lock. When the user unlocks it (slides), I need to relaunch the application.

For that i used the following code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

Still the application doesn't relaunch after the screen is unlocked. Help, what should i do to make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to do anything for that. If an application is open before locking the iphone, it will be open, if you unlock it again.

`setIdleTimerDisabled` just ensures, that the device won't go to sleep on its own, while your application is running. In most cases you shouldn't use this application-wide.

Comment: But, when the application re-opens it gets stuck for a few seconds (like 2 seconds). So i thought of re-launching the application to prevent this ? (Is this a good approach and will apple approve it?)

Comment: No, if your App freezes while waking up, it probably has some problem that will surface under other circumstances.  Having your app periodically restarted is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: Also there is NO way to restart your application. You're even not allowed to close down your application on yourself. If you do it, this *is* a rejection reason. You're freezing app is probably your own problem (some part of your code), as other apps don't have that problem.